# Formatting json data to group by items

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, grouping

I have angular application where I am trying to get json in particular format.
I am pulling data from db and database has table data as

```
Country State 
China   chungchong
India   hyderabad 
USA     florida
India   delhi
USA     redmond
```

I am trying to get json with list of countries and each country having cities in an array.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('CountyStatesService', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/GetCountryStates/');
    }
])
```

GetCountryStates() method is a csharp method which just returns list of all data from the table.

I am trying to get json sorted/grouped by in the below format

```
 data: [
               { text: "China", items: [
        {text: "chungchong"}
        ] },
               {
                   text: "India", items: [
                   { text: "Hyderabad" },
                   { text: "Delhi" }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   text: "USA", items: [
                   { text: "Florida" },
                   { text: "Redmond" }
                   ]
               }
            ]
```

But I am getting json with out grouping. How can I achieve json format as expected.

C# code

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CountrieStatesClass> GetCountryState()
    {
        return GetStructuredJson();
    }

public IEnumerable<CountrieStatesClass> GetStructuredJson()
    {
        List<CountrieStatesClass> locations = new List<CountrieStatesClass>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select * from tblCountryStateDetails";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CountrieStatesClass location = new CountrieStatesClass
                    {
                        CountryName = (string)reader["CountryName"],
            StateName=(string)reader["StateName"]
                    };
                    locations.Add(location);
                }
            }
            return locations;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `CountrieStatesClass` look like?  does it support the nested format you want?

Comment: it has string CountryName get;set; and string StateName get;set;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Off, I would define `CountrieStatesClass` to look more like this

```
public class CountrieStatesClass
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public List<State> Items {get; set;}
}

public class State
{
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

Then, load your data like this

```
CountrieStatesClass location = new CountrieStatesClass
{
    Text = (string)reader["CountryName"], 
    Items = new List<State>{new State{ Text = (string)reader["StateName"] } }
};
locations.Add(location);
```

Then, you use linq

```
return locations
    .GroupBy(l => l.Text)
    .Select(grp => new CountrieStatesClass
    {
        Text = grp.Key,
        Items = grp.SelectMany(l => l.Items).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

And then you just serialize that object with whatever serialization tool you're already using.

---

**note** There are better ways to load your data.  I personally use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), but there are a bunch of other tools out there too.

Comment: is there any option to group by with this traditional ado.net approach?

Comment: @Chandana My answer applies to whatever approach you were using before.  the note about Entity framework was just a note.  I've moved it to the end to avoid confusion.

Comment: could you please edit the below.
NewList to new List

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one Linq statement.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
    {
        ...

        var answers = objList.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Select(x => new { Category = x.Key, Items = x.ToArray() });
        response.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answers), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response.Headers.Add("total", objList.Count().ToString());
        return ResponseMessage(response);

    }
```